# Set php variable by jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

set php variable by jquery variable?

in php:

```
<?php
   $id1 = id1;
?>
```

in jquery :

```
var id1 = $('.test').val();
```

Comment: Please try to explain properly.

Comment: Use ajax to send it back to the page, JQUERY is client side while PHP is server side. The only way to interact between them is to send it then load that ajax result into a div

Comment: `id1` is not available in PHP. PHP loads first (on the server).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  PHP runs on the server side (and returns HTML); JQuery (i.e. JS) runs on the browser.  What you are seeking does not seem to make sense.  If you are trying to 'send' a JS variable/value to PHP, you can do it in many ways.  You'll have to narrow down your question

Comment: clearshot66  Without
  Ajax is not possible?

Comment: you can't do that  until ajax come into picture

Comment: @mrreza no. Depends on your setup and what you want but without a request and return from the server it's not possible

Comment: clearshot66  Logic. thanks

Comment: May I ask what you want to do with it?

Comment: clearshot66  solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following on your Client Side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="someId">Meh</p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $.get("some_page.php",{ id1: "id1"});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On your PHP file:

```
<?php
 $var = $_GET['id1'];
 echo($var);
?>
```

However, I recommend using plain JavaScript to do this. See [XMLHttpRequest();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)